# Dissecting Number Ranges

Tags: php, mysql, range, between

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to generate a WHERE query. I asked another question earlier, which was similar, but I will get right to the point on this one.

Given a collection of number ranges, ie `1-1000`, `1500-1600` it is quite simple to create a mysql where condition to select records which are between these values.

ie, you would just do:

`WHERE (lft BETWEEN 1 and 1000) OR (lft BETWEEN 1500-1600)`. However, what if you wanted to incorporate a NOT BETWEEN as well.

For example, if you define several rules, like...

- ALLOW BETWEEN 1 - 1000
- ALLOW BETWEEN 1500 - 1600
- ALLOW BETWEEN 1250 - 1300
- DENY BETWEEN 25 - 50

How can I merge these rules in order to efficiently generate a WHERE condition. 
I would like the WHERE to dissect the `ALLOW BETWEEN 1 - 1000` in order to create a gap in it. So that it would become `1-24` and `51-1000`. Because the DENY rule is defined after the first rule, it "overwrites" the previous rules.

As another example, 
Say that you have

- ALLOW BETWEEN 5 - 15
- DENY BETWEEN 10 - 50
- ALLOW BETWEEN 45 - 60

Then I would like to generate a WHERE condition which would allow me to do:

`WHERE (lft BETWEEN 5 and 9) OR (lft BETWEEN 45 and 60)`.

## Notes (Edits)

- Also, the maximum range that would ever allowed is 1 - 5600000. (Which would be 'Earth') ie. Allow everything on Earth.
- The number ranges are actually the LEFT values in a NESTED SET MODEL. These aren't unique keys. 
  You can read why I want to do this in this question I asked earlier. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020553/generating-a-mysql-between-where-condition-based-on-an-access-ruleset
- **Possible important note on my number ranges** I maybe shouldn't have used the sample example which I did, but one important note about the nature of the number ranges is that, the ranges should actually always entirely consume or be consumed by a previous rule. For example, I used the example above, 10-50 allow, and deny 45-60. This wouldn't actually ever happen in my data set. It would actually be, `allow 10-50`, then the DENY would have to either be entirely consumed by that range, ie, 34-38. OR, entirely consume the previous rule. `9-51`. This is because the ranges actually **represent lft and rgt values in a nested set model** and you cannot have overlaps like I presented.

I didn't think to mention that when asking the question, but after seeing the working sample code below, I can see that this note is actually important.

(Edited example mysql to include OR instead of AND as per comment below)

Comment: That's logically impossible, since a number cannot be between 5 and 9, and also between 45 and 60. Perhaps you mean 'OR'?

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, you are right. It is logically impossible. I don't know what I want thinking. I did intend to say OR.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Honestly, why bother?  As long as the key you're querying against is indexed, just put the multiple queries in there:

```
WHERE (foo BETWEEN 1 AND 1000 
        OR foo BETWEEN 1500 AND 1600
        OR foo BETWEEN 1250 AND 1300
    ) AND (
        foo NOT BETWEEN 25 AND 50
    )
```

You could squeze a slight bit of efficiency by building a dissector, but I would question if it's worth it.  All the WHERE clause items would be off of an index, so you're not preventing any hard operation from occurring (meaning you're not stopping a full-table-scan by doing it).

So rather than spending time building a system to do it for you, just implement an easy solution (`OR`ing together the Allows, and `AND`ing together the Denys) and move on to more important things.  Then if it becomes a problem later, revisit it then.  But I really don't think this will ever become too big of a problem...

**Edit** Ok, here's a very simple algorithm for doing this.  It uses strings as the data store, so it's reasonably efficient for smaller numbers (below 1 million):

```
class Dissector {
    protected $range = '';
    public function allow($low, $high) {
        $this->replaceWith($low, $high, '1');
    }
    public function deny($low, $high) {
        $this->replaceWith($low, $high, '0');
    }
    public function findRanges() {
        $matches = array();
        preg_match_all(
            '/(?<!1)1+(?!1)/', 
            $this->range, 
            $matches, 
            PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
        );
        return $this->decodeRanges($matches[0]);
    }
    public function generateSql($field) {
        $ranges = $this->findRanges();
        $where = array();
        foreach ($ranges as $range) {
            $where[] = sprintf(
                '%s BETWEEN %d AND %d', 
                $field, 
                $range['from'], 
                $range['to']
            );
        }
        return implode(' OR ', $where);
    }
    protected function decodeRanges(array $matches) {
        $range = array();
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $range[] = array(
                'from' => $match[1] + 1, 
                'to' => ($match[1] + strlen($match[0]))
            );
        }
        return $range;
    }
    protected function normalizeLengthTo($size) {
        if (strlen($this->range) < $size) {
            $this->range = str_pad($this->range, $size, '0');
        }
    }
    protected function replaceWith($low, $high, $character) {
        $this->normalizeLengthTo($high);
        $length = $high - $low + 1;
        $stub = str_repeat($character, $length);
        $this->range = substr_replace($this->range, $stub, $low - 1, $length);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$d = new Dissector();
$d->allow(1, 10);
$d->deny(5, 15);
$d->allow(10, 20);
var_dump($d->findRanges());
var_dump($d->generateSql('foo'));
```

Generates:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["from"]=>
    int(1)
    ["to"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["from"]=>
    int(10)
    ["to"]=>
    int(20)
  }
}
string(44) "foo BETWEEN 1 AND 4 OR foo BETWEEN 10 AND 20"
```

Comment: Great idea, however, it doesn't deal with the situation of conditions overriding each other depending on order of those conditions (as per his second example).

Comment: @Brian: Sure it does.  That's why you `AND` together the Deny bits.  `WHERE (foo BETWEEN 5 AND 15 OR foo BETWEEN 45 AND 60) AND (foo NOT BETWEEN 10 AND 50)` would correctly match `9` and correctly not match `12`...  The `OR` requires that *one or more* of the `Allows` match, and the `AND` requires that none of the Denys match (well, technically that they all match, but since we're negating it with a `NOT` it becomes positive)...

Comment: But what about 46.  The where clause you describe would not match 46 but Laykes wanted it included because the last rule allow 45-60.

Comment: @Brian: It would not match 46 because it's explicitly denied.  I think his last example is flawed (the sql bit), since the first one and the first half of the second follow the Deny-first pattern, but the second half of the last one does not.  Therefore, I assume that he's using deny-first, and that 46 should not match.

Comment: That could well be the case and Laykes doesn't appear to be chiming in on our conversation so it's hard to tell.  I had assumed a strict order precedence from his sentence, "Because the DENY rule is defined after the first rule, it "overwrites" the previous rules."

Comment: Yeah, this wouldn't work. If you want to understand more behind this question you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020553/generating-a-mysql-between-where-condition-based-on-an-access-ruleset

Comment: I'm using a FIFO. So the rules that are declared first are assigned and resolved first. Hence, any DENY that is declared after an ALLOW, will override the ALLOW.

Comment: @Laykes: I've added a solution that will handle this as well.  It's quite simple, and should be easy to understand as there really isn't much to the logic, it's just storing the range as a string...

Comment: Wow, ircmaxell, that appears to handle everything I have thrown at it. http://codepad.viper-7.com/NSIPEN . A lot of my ranges might be in the millions. How does this perform. I can easily cache however if that is neccessary. (The upper boundary is one higher than it should be, though that should be an easy fix. For example, 1-50 allow, 45-60 deny, should resolve to allow 1-44, not 1-45 as your sample does. Butyeah it works fantastically).

Comment: @Laykes: good point.  I fixed the algorithm to include the proper upper bound.  As far as performance, it'll be very fast no matter what you throw at it since everything is a simple string operation.  However, it will use a lot of memory (max allowed or denied id == number of bytes).  So if the max id you use is 10,000,000 it will add 10mb of overhead.  But if you give it the memory, it'll be fast (I just tested 60 million, and it took well less than 0.01 seconds since it's one allocation, but it also took nearly 30mb of ram)...

Comment: Okay thanks ircmaxell. This is the backend administration panel, so I don't actually mind about the memory usage. It isn't a core aspect of the site. Also, I think I will try and cache the SQL string anyway, and invalidate it when the input arguments change. I'm impressed at how quick it is.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a little time trying to solve this (it's a neat problem), and came up with this. It's not optimal, nor am I guaranteeing it's perfect, but it might get you started:

```
<?php

/*$cond = array(
    array('a', 5, 15),
    array('d', 9, 50),
    array('a', 45, 60)
);*/

$cond = array(
    array('a', 1, 1000),
    array('a', 1500, 1600),
    array('a', 1250, 1300),
    array('d', 25, 50)
);

$allow = array();

function merge_and_sort(&$allow)
{
    usort($allow, function($arr1, $arr2)
    {
        if ($arr1[0] > $arr2[0])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    });

    $prev = false;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($allow); $i++)
    {
        $c = $allow[$i];
        if ($i > 0 && $allow[$i][0] < $allow[$i - 1][1])
        {
            if ($allow[$i][1] <= $allow[$i - 1][1])
            {
                unset($allow[$i]);
            }
            else
            {
                $allow[$i - 1][1] = $allow[$i][1];
                unset($allow[$i]);
            }
        }
    }

    usort($allow, function($arr1, $arr2)
    {
        if ($arr1[0] > $arr2[0])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    });
}

function remove_cond(&$allow, $start, $end)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($allow); $i++)
    {
        if ($start > $allow[$i][0])
        {
            if ($end <= $allow[$i][1])
            {
                $temp = $allow[$i][1];
                $allow[$i][1] = $start;
                $allow []= array($end, $temp);
            }
            else
            {
                $found = false;
                for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($allow); $j++)
                {
                    if ($end >= $allow[$j][0] && $end < $allow[$j][1])
                    {
                        $found = true;
                        $allow[$j][0] = $end;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        unset($allow[$j]);
                    }
                }

                if (!$found)
                {
                    $allow[$i][1] = $start;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach ($cond as $c)
{
    if ($c[0] == "a")
    {
        $allow []= array($c[1], $c[2]);

        merge_and_sort($allow);
    }
    else
    {
        remove_cond($allow, $c[1], $c[2]);
        merge_and_sort($allow);
    }
}

var_dump($allow);
```

The last `var_dump` outputs:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1)
    [1]=>
    int(25)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(50)
    [1]=>
    int(1000)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1250)
    [1]=>
    int(1300)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(1500)
    [1]=>
    int(1600)
  }
}
```

*Edited to use the first example instead of the second.*

Comment: (Upvote for the effort) I will try and see where it is going wrong. It works on non complex overlaps, but when you start to do some crazy things, it falls down. For example, in this sample, I would not want ANYTHING to be allowed. Because the final rule actually disallows everything.  http://codepad.viper-7.com/hElHp9

Comment: Yeah, I'll put some more thought into it too. I tried updating it to cover your test case and promptly broke my the first test case, so, yeah. :) I'll edit/comment here if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 0):

I would process the instructions one at a time creating a list of numbers that should be included.  Then finally translating that list into a set of ranges for the where clause.  Here is some pseudo code:

```
$numbers = array();
foreach (conditions as $condition) {
    if ($condition is include) {
        for ($i = $condition.start; $i <= $condition.end; $i++) {
            $numbers[$i] = true;
        }
    } else {
        for ($i = $condition.start; $i <= $condition.end; $i++) {
            unset($numbers[$i]);
        }
    }
}
ksort($numbers);
```

Comment: Yeah, Brian, I thought about that. The problem is that I could potentially have about 5.6 million range. For example, the ROOT node in my nested set model is "Earth". Which means I would want to include all resources to this user inside of Earth. I really don't know how I can do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

I asked on IRC and received two responses. I'm going to post them both so that other people might benefit (and so that I don't lose them since I will take a look in detail at them both shortly).

## Example 1 TML

```
<pre><?php

$cond = array(
    array('a', 5, 15),
    array('a', 5, 15),
    array('d', 9, 50),
    array('a', 45, 60),
    array('a', 2, 70),
    array('d', 1, 150),
);



function buildAcl($set) {
    $allow = array();
    foreach($set as $acl) {
        $range = range($acl[1], $acl[2]);
        switch($acl[0]) {
            case 'a':
                $allow = array_unique(array_merge(array_values($allow), $range));
                break;
            case 'd':
                foreach($range as $entry) {
                    unset($allow[array_search($entry, $allow)]);
                }
        }
    }
    return $allow;
}

var_dump(buildAcl($cond));
var_dump(buildAcl(array(array('a', 5, 15), array('d', 10, 50), array('a', 45, 60))));
```

## Example 2 (matslin)

```
<?php
$conds = array(
    array('a', 5, 15),
    array('a', 5, 15),
    array('d', 9, 50),
    array('a', 45, 60),
    array('a', 2, 70),
    array('d', 1, 150),
);

$segments = array();

foreach($conds as $cond)
{
    print($cond[0] . ': ' . $cond[1] . ' - ' . $cond[2] . "\n");
    if ($cond[0] == 'a')
    {
        $new_segments = array();
        $inserted = false;
        $prev_segment = false;

        foreach($segments as $segment)
        {
            if ($segment['begin'] > $cond[2])
            {
                $new_segments[] = array('begin' => $cond[1], 'end' => $cond[2]);
                $new_segments[] = $segment;
                $inserted = true;
                print("begun\n");
                continue;
            }

            if ($segment['end'] < $cond[1])
            {
                print("end\n");
                $new_segments[] = $segment;
                continue;
            }

            if ($cond[1] < $segment['begin'])
            {
                $segment['begin'] = $cond[1];
            }

            if ($cond[2] > $segment['end'])
            {
                $segment['end'] = $cond[2];
            }

            $inserted = true;

            if (
                $prev_segment &&
                ($prev_segment['begin'] <= $segment['begin']) &&
                ($prev_segment['end'] >= $segment['end'])
            )
            {
                print("ignore identical\n");
                continue;
            }

            print("default\n");
            $prev_segment = $segment;
            $new_segments[] = $segment;
        }

        if (!$inserted)
        {
            print("inserted at end\n");
            $new_segments[] = array('begin' => $cond[1], 'end' => $cond[2]);
        }

        $segments = $new_segments;
        print("---\n");
    }

    if ($cond[0] == 'd')
    {
        $new_segments = array();

        foreach($segments as $segment)
        {
            # not contained in segment
            if ($segment['begin'] > $cond[2])
            {
                print("delete segment is in front\n");
                $new_segments[] = $segment;
                continue;
            }

            if ($segment['end'] < $cond[1])
            {
                print("delete segment is behind\n");
                $new_segments[] = $segment;
                continue;
            }

            # delete whole segment
            if (
                ($segment['begin'] >= $cond[1]) &&
                ($segment['end'] <= $cond[2])
            )
            {
                print("delete whole segment\n");
                continue;
            }

            # delete starts at boundary
            if ($cond[1] <= $segment['begin'])
            {
                print("delete at boundary start\n");
                $segment['begin'] = $cond[2];
                $new_segments[] = $segment;
                continue;
            }
            # delete ends at boundary
            if ($cond[2] >= $segment['end'])
            {
                print("delete at boundary end\n");
                $segment['end'] = $cond[1];
                $new_segments[] = $segment;
                continue;
            }

            # split into two segments
            print("split into two\n");
            $segment_pre = array('begin' => $segment['begin'], 'end' => $cond[1]);
            $segment_post = array('begin' => $cond[2], 'end' => $segment['end']);

            $new_segments[] = $segment_pre;
            $new_segments[] = $segment_post;
        }

        print("--\n");
        $segments = $new_segments;
    }

    print("----\n");
    var_dump($segments);
    print("----\n");
}

var_dump($segments);
```